# Images not aligning up

Tags: html, css, image, visual-studio-code

I have an issue where whenever I try to line up my images. It seems to not line up.
I do not know if this is an image issue but I could use some help.
I am new to this so if this is a easy fix from my side I apologize.

```css
.portfolio-item-wrapper2 {
    display: flex;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;

}

.portfolio-item-wrapper2 {
    position: relative;

}

.portfolio-img-background2 {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img-text-wrapper2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```
<div class="content=wrapper2">
    <div class="portfolio-items-wrapper2">
        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper2">
            <div class="portfolio-img-background2">
                <div class="img-text-wrapper2">
                    <div class="logo-wrapper2">
                        <img src="\\kcfs04\StudentHome\20023600\Downloads\C.png" />

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="content=wrapper3">
    <div class="portfolio-items-wrapper3">
        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper3">
            <div class="portfolio-img-background3">
                <div class="img-text-wrapper3">
                    <div class="logo-wrapper3">
                        <img src="\\kcfs04\StudentHome\20023600\Downloads\G.png" />

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the issue:
[image: This here.]

I need them both to be side by side because I will be adding more below but in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

first, dont use css grid and  flexbox with same time and you can use position relative property